# Binding itemsource to multiple Collections in the view model

Tags: c#, mvvm

i have 5 buttons and a ListBox

with each button click i want to bind the ListBox itemssource to a different collection that the Button refers to.

so far what i have in mind is 
making a single command that takes one parameter which is for example the buttons name and caling a function that contains a switch statement and then do change the itemssource binding in code.

i am new to mvvm, could you please give me a better way?

Comment: I think that's the best way to do it. Pass the button as the CommandParameter so you have the button object and not a string. You might be able to do this another way by having the buttons modify a property and then having the ListBox trigger a change of its datacontext based on this, but its overkill. Your way is clean and fine.

Comment: @MillieSmith i asked the question because i wanted to keep it clean an not doing the binding in code behind

Comment: I know. Hook the same command to all the buttons and pass the button as the CommandParameter. Then do your switch and set the itemssource of your listbox in there. I really do think its the cleanest way.

Comment: By the way, passing the button is probably better than passing its name.

Comment: @MillieSmith and i do have to have a Collection that is called currentItemsource and set its value to the collection that the button refers to?

Comment: @user1492051, is using just a single Command a strict requirement? And will the number of the collections always be 5, or will your code eventually have to deal with a variable number of collections?

Comment: @elgonzo using a command is not strict requirement, and yes it will always be 5, but it has to be buttons so i think it has to be commands then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all expose each of the collections on your ViewModel as well as a place holder collection `CurrentList`.  Then you can bind your buttons to the same command but in the CommandParameter of each one you bind to the associated list:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SwitchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding List1}">List 1</Button>
<Button Command="{Binding SwitchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding List2}">List 2</Button>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentList}"></ListView>
```

In the execute method of your command you simply set the `CurrentList` to the parameter:

```
_viewModel.CurrentList = (List<string>) parameter;
```